# Replace content of a div on hover with fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the content of a `div` when user hovers on it. I have created two `div`'s. The `foreground` `div` is the default and on hover action I want to hide the `foreground` and show `background` `div`.

```js
$('.background').hide();

$(".card-text").mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("enter");
  $(this).next('.foreground').fadeOut();
  $(this).next('.background').fadeIn();
});

$(".card-text").mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("leave");
  $(this).next('.foreground').fadeIn();
  $(this).next('.background').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.card-text{
  background-color: #d7f1f5;
  padding: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-text">
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>MyTitle 1</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="background">
    <p>Hoveerr 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: black; padding: 5px; margin:50px 0px;"></div>

<div class="card-text">
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>MyTitle2 </p>
    <p>Bla bla bla 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="background">
    <p>Hoveerr 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, nothing happens... What am I missing here?

Comment: use `$(this).find('.foreground').fadeOut();` instead of `.next()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `next()`, which is looking for siblings, instead of `find()` which looks for children.

Note in the example below that I also added calls to `stop()` so that the flickering, which occurs when the event is called multiple times as the DOM updates, is avoided.

```js
$(".card-text").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find('.foreground').stop(true).fadeOut();
  $(this).find('.background').stop(true).fadeIn();
});

$(".card-text").on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find('.foreground').stop(true).fadeIn();
  $(this).find('.background').stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.background { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-text">
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>MyTitle 1</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="background">
    <p>Hoveerr 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: black; padding: 5px;"></div>

<div class="card-text">
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>MyTitle2 </p>
    <p>Bla bla bla 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="background">
    <p>Hoveerr 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

***However*** it's worth noting that you should use CSS where possible as it performs much better than JS. To do this you can hook `:hover` states to the `.card-text` and `transition` the child elements based on their `opacity`. Try this:

```css
.card-text {
  display: grid;
}

.card-text div {
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.foreground { opacity: 1; }
.background { opacity: 0; }

.card-text:hover .foreground { opacity: 0; }
.card-text:hover .background { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="card-text">
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>MyTitle 1</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="background">
    <p>Hoveerr 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: black; padding: 5px;"></div>

<div class="card-text">
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>MyTitle2 </p>
    <p>Bla bla bla 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="background">
    <p>Hoveerr 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for tip about the '.stop(true)'!

Comment: No problem. I just updated the answer to show you an approach using CSS alone, which would be far better to use in practice.